# How to set a default value to one of the values pulled from the SQL Data Source in a ASP.NET DropDownList Control?

Tags: default-value, object-reference

I want to set the default value of my ASP.NET DropDownList equal to one of the values in the DropDownList. For example my list is populated with ~ALL~, BrickandMortar, Distribution, Employee, Partner, Premier, Retail, and Wholesale and I want the default value of the drop down to be Retail. I have tried this code in my Page Load function:

```
if (CustomerClassList != null)
{
CustomerClassList.SelectedValue = CustomerClassDropDrown.Items.FindByValue("Retail").Value;
}
```

I also I put this line of code at the start of my class

```
DropDownList CustomerClassList = new DropDownList();
```

So the error I'm getting back is that there is no object reference so I'm not sure what to do. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Your class that holds the list of items might be instantiated (not null) but that doesn't mean it has any items, check the count property or length property of the list if you have one  on your class and see if there are any items first before you do a search...your list class may require you to have items prior to searching